# How can i print differences, similarities and change in field names if any between 2 Json files in Kotlin?

Tags: json, kotlin

> I have a JSON file/object 1 and  want to compare it with other JSON file/object and show the similarities,differences and change in field/key names or values if any in Kotlin.
> I know Comparable implementation but is there any other library would ease this task and reduce complexity.
>
> I'm concern about how to show differences and similarities per key and values in each JSON.
> i tried in java using JSONParser implementation but don't know how to implement it in Kotlin.

```
package com.main;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import com.google.common.collect.MapDifference;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;


public class TestJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            
            Object obj1 = parser.parse(new FileReader("D:/test1.json"));
            //Object obj2 = parser.parse(new FileReader("D:/test2.json"));
            
            JSONArray jsonSites1 = (JSONArray)  obj1;
            //JSONArray jsonSites2 = (JSONArray)  obj2;
            JSONObject leftMap = (JSONObject) jsonSites1.get(0);
            //JSONObject leftMap = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("D:/test3.json"));
            
            JSONObject rightMap = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("D:/test2.json"));
            
           
            Map<String, Object> leftFlatMap = FlatMapUtil.flatten(leftMap);
            Map<String, Object> rightFlatMap = FlatMapUtil.flatten(rightMap);
            MapDifference<String, Object> difference = Maps.difference(leftFlatMap, rightFlatMap);
            
            System.out.println("Entries only on left\n--------------------------");
            difference.entriesOnlyOnLeft().forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + value));
            
            System.out.println("\n\nEntries only on right\n--------------------------");
            difference.entriesOnlyOnRight().forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + value));

            System.out.println("\n\nEntries differing\n--------------------------");
            difference.entriesDiffering().forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + value));

            System.out.println("\n\nEntries in common\n--------------------------");
            difference.entriesInCommon().forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + value));

            
            
            
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
//String json = leftMap.toJSONString();
//String birthday = (String) data.get("birthday");
//System.out.println(json);
//System.out.println(birthday);
```

Comment: Kotlin has a [JSON library](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-j-s-o-n/) I would recommend looking it over, and coming back with an attempt at what you're looking to do.

Comment: Note, that's for Javascript only. Klaxon is a Kotlin-centric JSON library, and there's also Moshi which is very Kotlin-friendly.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Great! Thanks for the input.

Comment: How can i compare 2 json's field by field for equality but ??

Comment: you need to tell us what you have tried

Comment: @sidgate updated my java implementation.